# wso2 DAS use mysql + clustering APIM,can not show STATS with this error

Tags: mysql, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

1.first i use h2 database clustering apim with das .APIM and DAS work well with each other

2.When i changed mysql ,APIM also good,but DAS not .then i can not watch stats.

```
    [2016-10-11 17:11:13,335]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.CappAxis2Deployer} -  Undeploying Faulty Carbon Application On : /home/dgp_aop/tomcat/apim-app/das/repository/deployment/server/carbonapps/API_Manager_Analytics_RDBMS.car
[2016-10-11 17:11:13,336]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager} -  Deploying Carbon Application : API_Manager_Analytics_RDBMS.car...
[2016-10-11 17:11:13,351] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager} -  Carbon Application : APIM_STAT_CAPP_v1.0.3 already exists. Two applications can't have the same Id. Deployment aborted.
[2016-10-11 17:11:13,351] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager} -  Error occurred while deploying Carbon Application
org.wso2.carbon.CarbonException: Carbon Application : APIM_STAT_CAPP_v1.0.3 already exists. Two applications can't have the same Id. Deployment aborted.
        at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager.deployCarbonApp(ApplicationManager.java:237)
        at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.CappAxis2Deployer.deploy(CappAxis2Deployer.java:72)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.startListener(RepositoryListener.java:371)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.checkRepository(SchedulerTask.java:59)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.run(SchedulerTask.java:67)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.runAxisDeployment(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:93)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.run(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2016-10-11 17:11:13,352]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager} -  Reverting successfully deployed artifcats in this CApp : APIM_STAT_CAPP_v1.0.3
```

Comment: Do you still have any issues in viewing stats? You said `then i can watch stats`. Also, that cApp was successfully deployed.

Comment: sorry,my fault.I eat my 'not'.my stats is still not work.

Answer (score 1):

As per [1] this should be due to existing cApp. When you change the DB to mysql, first of all you have to remove the DAS_HOME/repository/data folder, and also DAS_HOME/tmp directory.

[1] [WSO2 Application server CarbonAppUploader will not overwrite existing artifact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21124656/wso2-application-server-carbonappuploader-will-not-overwrite-existing-artifact)